# How to get the exact child element with corresponding parent only from multilevel embedded MongoDB document using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Trying to get exact child document with it's corresponding parent document from embedded MongoDB document using C#  but query return all the child and corresponding parent and others . how to set parameter to 
get the exact match with Filter and findOptions. My expected result will be Channel 1 -> Episode 1 & it's Child Track which id is given .
Here is my code:

```
// Class
namespace CrudWithMultilvelNestedDoc
{
    public class Channel
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Episode[] Episodes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Episode
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Track[] Tracks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Track
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Like[] Likes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Like
    {
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

//Code
var chanelId = "5e4606e6ae7b090688671416";
var episodeId = "5e46071d385a672b0cea0f86";
var trackId = "5e460dbe2bc5e70c9cfeac21";

var filter = Builders<Channel>.Filter.And(
             Builders<Channel>.Filter.Where(x => x.Id == chanelId),
             Builders<Channel>.Filter.Eq("Episodes._id", episodeId),
             Builders<Channel>.Filter.Eq("Episodes.Tracks._id", trackId));
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

// Data
{"_id":"5e4606e6ae7b090688671416","Name":"Channel 1","Episodes":[{"_id":"5e46071d385a672b0cea0f86","Name":"Episode 1","Tracks":[{"_id":"5e460dbe2bc5e70c9cfeac21","Name":"Trak 1","Likes":[{"_id":"5e4635d41f949d43a8194790","Name":"Like 1"},{"_id":"5e464e1ccfa17a25181234f6","Name":"Like 2"},{"_id":"5e464e94776dc808383326d5","Name":"Like 3"}]},{"_id":"5e4612d60747a2121870c815","Name":"Trak 2","Likes":[]}]},{"_id":"5e460851d29c1b3df4d27b7d","Name":"Episode 2","Tracks":[{"_id":"5e460e307ca6843758ce814e","Name":"Trak 1","Likes":[{"_id":"5e4686aa2813d41fa428b621","Name":"Like 1"}]}]}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your document is multilevel you have to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) operator. In C# it's easy to use LINQ for such query since it automatically generates `$filter` behind the scenes and you preserve strongly-typed query:

```
var q = from channel in mongoDBCollection.AsQueryable()
        from episode in channel.Episodes
        select new Episode()
        {
            Id = episode.Id,
            Name = episode.Name,
            Tracks = episode.Tracks.Where(x => x.Id == trackId)
        };

var query = q.Where(x => x.Tracks.Any());
var result = query.ToList();
```

The Aggregation Pipeline that gets generated by MongoDB .NET driver looks like below:

```
{ 
    "aggregate" : "col", 
    "pipeline" : [
        { "$unwind" : "$Episodes" }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "Id" : "$Episodes._id", 
                "Name" : "$Episodes.Name", 
                "Tracks" : { 
                    "$filter" : { 
                        "input" : "$Episodes.Tracks", 
                        "as" : "x", 
                        "cond" : { "$eq" : ["$$x._id", "5e460dbe2bc5e70c9cfeac21"] } 
                    } 
                }, 
                "_id" : 0 
            } 
        }, 
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "Tracks" : { 
                    "$ne" : null, 
                    "$not" : { "$size" : 0 } 
                } 
            } 
        }], 
    "cursor" : { }, 
}
```

EDIT:

To improve the performance of above query you can consider filtering on `channel` level by adding `where` statement:

```
from channel in mongoDBCollection.AsQueryable()
where channel.Id == channelId
```

EDIT: it becomes a little bit more tricky when you want to return `Channel` as well. My suggestion would be to return an anomyous type which contains both `Channel` and `Episode` and combine them in memory since it will allow you to run most of filtering on the database side and get the best performance:

```
var q = from channel in mongoDBCollection.AsQueryable()
        where channel.Id == "5e4606e6ae7b090688671416"
        from episode in channel.Episodes
        select new 
        {
            Channel = new Channel(){ Id = channel.Id, Name = channel.Name},
            Episode = new Episode()
            {
                Id = episode.Id,
                Name = episode.Name,
                Tracks = episode.Tracks.Where(x => x.Id == trackId)
            }
        };

var query = q.Where(x => x.Episode.Tracks.Any());
var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks mickl, get another issue here -
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Cru
Tracks = episode.Tracks.Where(x => x.Id == trackId) This section get error-
StatedWithMultilvelNestedDoc.Track>' to 'CrudWithMultilvelNestedDoc.Track[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: @KhairulAlam ah, yes, sorry forgot to mention - I had to change Array to IEnumerable, you can do the same or use anonymous type as a return value

Comment: This extract Episode and it's child but i am trying it's parent Channel info also. Can you please check this again.

Comment: @KhairulAlam modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

here's a lambda version of mickl's answer and also with the channel info retained:

```cs
var result = collection.AsQueryable()
               .Where(c => c.Id == "5e4606e6ae7b090688671416")
               .SelectMany(c => c.Episodes,
                           (c, e) => new
                           {
                               cid = c.Id,
                               cname = c.Name,
                               eid = e.Id,
                               ename = e.Name,
                               etracks = (Track[])e.Tracks.Where(t => t.Id == "5e460dbe2bc5e70c9cfeac21")
                           })
               .Where(x => x.etracks.Any())
               .Select(x => new Channel
               {
                   ID = x.cid,
                   Name = x.cname,
                   Episodes = new Episode[] {
                       new Episode {
                           Id = x.eid,
                           Name = x.ename,
                           Tracks = x.etracks } }
               })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Inner Exception:   FormatException: Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class CrudWithMultilvelNestedDoc.Episode.

Comment: Exception: Command aggregate failed: input to $filter must be an array not object.